# Unanswered Questions and chances of Decreasing Unanswered

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates, unanswered-questions

Hello fellow stack members I have been trying to decrease the unanswered questions for this website, and even map out duplicates in the math that I know. You could look at my recent answered questions. My question is that is this tactic worthwhile to decrease the unanswered questions and can we notify users to their answers?

Comment: "I have been trying to decrease the unanswered questions for this website" thank you.

Comment: Users _always_ get a notification when you post an answer on their questions. Or you meant something different?

Comment: @Magic_Isa I am trying to see if we can like change the conditions of unanswered to an unaccepted answer because then there would be less unanswered questions or is that a thing?

Comment: I am still trying to figure out the stats for unanswered and accepted answered questions

Comment: I don't get your first comment

Comment: related [Unanswered Questions and Statistics/Review Impacts](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8583/unanswered-questions-and-statistics-review-impacts?rq=1) ?

Comment: got it now. "I am trying to see if we can like change the conditions of unanswered to an unaccepted" no. If it doesn't have an answer then why to say  _yes_ it has an unaccepted answer.

Comment: There is a chatroom called [The Crusade of Answers](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/9141). (Admittedly, it isn't visited by many users.) See also [the room description](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26814/list-of-chatrooms/26825#26825) in the list of chatrooms here on meta.

Comment: I would like to also suggest that if the unanswered questions you are encountering are very low quality, or dupes, that you vote to close them accordingly, and not provide an answer to such posts for the sole reason of decreasing the size of the "unanswered questions".  When closed, they can then be deleted, if users vote to do so, which is another avenue to get rid of the very low quality posts considered currently among some of the "unanswered".

Comment: Not all questions that go unanswered are questions worth answering, is my point.  Also, this isn't just about questions designated "unanswered" that are very low quality, there are bound to be a few that are dupes, some that could be migrated, and still more that are too broad, and/or are off-topic.

Comment: To reinforce @amWhy's comments, a question on the list of unanswered questions can leave that list in two different ways:  either they can be answered, or they can be deleted.  My guess is that 90%+ of the unanswered questions are not worth answering (they may be unclear, or "too local" (i.e. asking for an answer to a specific homework problem), or otherwise not worth answering or unanswerable)---see Sturgeon's law.  Nominating such questions for closure is a good way to remove them from the unanswered list.

Comment: EnlightenedFunky  I do have to thank you for bringing the topic of "unanswered questions" on this site,  which I have not reviewed in quite some time now.

Comment: @amWhy Yes I am trying also to understand the concept of the accepted answers and unanswered, and is there a way to mitigate a way to bring these questions out of unanswered. And your welcome.